# How to download maps for minecraft xbox one without a usb drive

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

So I always wanted to download and play Minecraft maps on my Xbox One or Xbox 360, but I don't have a USB stick can you help me?

Comment: So buy one? You literally could get a 4GB USB stick for $5 (USD)....

Answer (score -3):

I think you can try upload it from PC to phone and then from phone to console. Also you can try using disc. Inform me if you have tried.